# I have 100 points on Stack Overflow; why can't I set a bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I have 100 reputation points on Stack Overflow, yet I am prevented from offering a bounty on my question. Why is this?

Comment: You might want to link your accounts! Then you'll get a few more points. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you missed this in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> If, after two days, you still don't
>   have an answer you like, you can offer
>   a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question isn't eligible yet, you have to wait at least 48 hours.

Do you have a link?