# Why can't I add a bounty to a question?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I have 100 points on Stack Overflow; why can't I set a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23703/i-have-100-points-on-stack-overflow-why-cant-i-set-a-bounty)
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have 1000 reputation points and have been a member for a year.  It seems the bounty link has disappeared.  Here's the post I'm trying to add a bounty to [Working example of CreateJobObject/SetInformationJobObject pinvoke in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net)

Comment: the bounty can only be added to a question that is at least two days old. See the faq.

Comment: @OP Good question!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Found it as the first question in my search.  Gamecat, the faq blows compared to this question.  Good job, OP.

Comment: @Gamecat, you should have put it in an answer, man. elder totally snaked your cred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question is (as of writing) only 21 minutes old. From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.